# долгая загрузка Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, java-ee

Столкнулся с проблемой инициализации hibernate. Довольно долго грузит, около 15 секунд.

```
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            System.out.println("Фабрика создана");
            sessionFactory = new Configuration()
                    .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .addAnnotatedClass(ProfField.class)
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }
}
```

Вот лог:

```
Info:   Loading application [ChessmanWork] at [/ChessmanWork]
Info:   ChessmanWork was successfully deployed in 10 850 milliseconds.
Info:   Фабрика создана
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.7.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
WARN:   HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
WARN:   HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Info:   HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work?useSSL=FALSE&zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC]
Info:   HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Info:   HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
Info:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 30 (min=1)
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Info:   HHH10005002: No explicit CDI BeanManager reference was passed to Hibernate, but CDI is available on the Hibernate ClassLoader.
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Info:   Hibernate: select proffield0_.id_prof_field as id_prof_1_0_, proffield0_.prof_field as prof_fie2_0_ from prof_fields proffield0_
```

Как можно ускорить процесс или сделать автоматическую инициализацию SessionFactory?? Spring не использую

Comment: А что используете? CDI?

Answer (score 0):

HibernateUtil.java:

```java
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.Metadata;
import org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistry;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactory == null) {
            try {
                // Create registry
                registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

                // Create MetadataSources
                MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

                // Create Metadata
                Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

                // Create SessionFactory
                sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if (registry != null) {
                    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
                }
            }
        }
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static void shutdown() {
        if (registry != null) {
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
        }
    }
}
```

Так же стоит добавить коннектор к Базе Данныйх.
Это пишешь в xml файле с Хибернетом

```xml
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.hikaricp.internal.HikariCPConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.connectionTimeout">20000</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.minimumIdle">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.maximumPoolSize">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hikari.idleTimeout">300000</property>
```

В pom.xml добавляешь следующее:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```